# Soft credit amount token

Tags: civicontribute, soft-credit

I'd like to send thankyou letters to soft credit contributors, but I don't find a token for soft credit amount. Not even in CiviToken extension. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use my [Soft Credit Tokens](https://civicrm.org/extensions/soft-credit-tokens) extension for this.  Note that the README points out it only pulls the data for the most recent soft credit on the contact, which may not be the correct one.  This was due to a limitation that existed until Civi 5.43 - this *can* be fixed now, but I'm not really using the extension anymore so someone else will have to do it.

Comment: I can do it, but could you give me some information about the limitation you are writing about?

Comment: @masetto The [token dev docs](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/token) provide context, but in short - pre-5.43, most places tokens were rendered only knew the contact ID of the recipient, not the contribution ID.  So it was impossible to pull the soft credit by contribution ID.  Instead, this extension (and others, like CiviToken) work by finding the most recent soft credit associated with this person.  Which is good enough, unless the person receives 2 soft credits in a short period of time.